# Developing Increase/Decrease Slide Button using react-native?

Tags: react-native

I need to develop a knob that increases and decreases the value by sliding up or down. Does anyone have any idea how I could do this animation with the button?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use react-native-gesture-handler for detect fling move top and bottom and in the callback you can increase and decrease value of button